# Цвета в ProgressBar WP8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

Имеется Progressbar, заполняется от правильных ответов на вопросы.
Возможно ли сделать так чтобы при правильных ответах, заполнение шло зеленым цветом, при неправильном ответе красным.
Т.е. в зависимости от ответа выбирать каким цветом заполнять ячейку Progressbar(value=1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Такая возможность отсутствует. Делайте кастомный контрол.